System pages to disk and locks up (Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS)
I have Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS.
I mainly use it for web browsing (firefox) and playing a game (light usage),
Even so, it frequently seems to be paging to disk and frequently locks up.
My sys admin skills are poor.  What is recommended for figuring out the problem (likewise what is recommended for "cleanup")?
System specs (from what is reported in settings)
CPU: Intel® Core™ i5-2320 CPU @ 3.00GHz × 4
HD: Disc capacity 1TB
RAM: Memory 5.7GB

Start with your system specs.  RAM, hard drive, CPU, etc.
